# Calculate cumulative sum within group per day of observation in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and need your help for a relatively simple task. I have a data frame that includes numerous samples for which I have information of observations collected on different dates. The number of observation dates and number of observations within each date differ between samples. Short example of my data frame:

```
sampleID day    obs
sample-1   2   blue
sample-1   3    red
sample-1   3 yellow
sample-1   6  green
sample-1   6   blue
sample-1   6  black
sample-2   4   blue
sample-2   4 yellow
sample-2   8 orange
sample-2  10  black
sample-2  12    red
sample-3   1  white
sample-3   1  black
sample-3   5 orange
sample-3   5   blue
```

What I would like to have is an output table where the data is described as following:

```
sampleID day n_obs n_cumulative
sample-1   2     1            1
sample-1   3     2            3
sample-1   6     3            6
sample-2   4     2            2
sample-2   8     1            3
sample-2  10     1            4
sample-2  12     1            5
sample-3   1     2            2
sample-3   5     2            4
```

i.e. in each row I would like to have the sample ID, the day, the number of observations on that particular day for that particular sample and in the last column the cumulative sum of the number of observations for that particular sample. The type of observation (red, blue, …) doesn’t matter, I am interested in only the number of observations per collection day.

Thank you for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(sampleID, day, name = 'n_obs') %>%
  group_by(sampleID) %>%
  mutate(n_cumulative = cumsum(n_obs))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   sampleID [3]
  sampleID   day n_obs n_cumulative
  <fct>    <int> <int>        <int>
1 sample-1     2     1            1
2 sample-1     3     2            3
3 sample-1     6     3            6
4 sample-2     4     2            2
5 sample-2     8     1            3
6 sample-2    10     1            4
7 sample-2    12     1            5
8 sample-3     1     2            2
9 sample-3     5     2            4
```